# Python TypeError: 'str' object is not callable?

Tags: python

Meine Aufgabe ist ein einen von einem String den ersten, den mittleren und den letzten char anzeigen zu lassen. Beim letzten Char bekomme ich eine Fehlermeldung. Woran liegt das?

```html
txt = input("Original string: ",)
l = len(txt)

def mitte(txt):

    if len(txt)%2==0:
        i =int(len(txt)/2)-1
        return txt[i]+txt[i+1]
    else:
        return txt[int(len(txt)/2)]

res = txt[0]
res = res + mitte(txt)
res = res + str(l-1)
print(res)
```

Comment: @Guimoute, why?  It's a decimal string representation of a number (like `'2'`)

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-only site.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the last character of the string using `txt[-1]`:

```
txt = input("Original string: ",)
l = len(txt)

def mitte(txt):

    if len(txt)%2==0:
        i =int(len(txt)/2)-1
        return txt[i]+txt[i+1]
    else:
        return txt[int(len(txt)/2)]

res = txt[0] + mitte(txt) + txt[-1]
print(res)
```